# Selenium web driver issue with rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver, unicorn

I am facing a very wired issues, with selenium driver and webdrivers. you can see snippet of codebase that I am using.
But main issues is that this code working fine at some places like local server, direct via ruby file, on server console, direct via ruby file on server BUT when running with unicorn server, driver get stuck around line 32. I am not able to find any issues, no timeout error, it just get hanged.

I have used wait until, scroll upto element, full window before start **scraping**.

I am using below version :
Ruby  (2.6.3)
Rails (5.1.7)
unicorn (5.5.1)
selenium-webdriver (3.141.0)
webdrivers (4.1.0)

Application deployed at aws micro instance.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "webdrivers"

class Scrape 
 def initialize

  end

  def call 
        url3 = "https://pdonline.brisbane.qld.gov.au/MasterPlan/Modules/Enquirer/Propertysearch.aspx"       suburb = "paddington"       street_name = "Reading ST"

        street_no = 39
        client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
        client.read_timeout = 300 # seconds

        options = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Options.new
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, http_client: client, options: options
        driver.navigate.to url3

        sleep(10)
        abc = driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_RadWindow1_C_btnOk") rescue nil
        unless abc.nil?
          driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_RadWindow1_C_btnOk").click
          sleep(5)
          driver.navigate.to url3
        end
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_SuburbCombo_Input").send_keys("#{suburb}")
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_StreetCombo_Input").click
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_StreetCombo_Input").send_keys("#{street_name}")
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_FromStreetNumberTextBox").click
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_FromStreetNumberTextBox").send_keys("#{street_no}")
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_MainContent_btnSearch").click
        sleep(5)
        driver.find_element(xpath: "//*[@id='ctl00_MainContent_SearchResultsGrid_ctl00__0']/td[4]/a/img").click
        sleep(10)
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles.last)

        abc = driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_RadWindow1_C_btnOk") rescue nil
        abc.nil? ? nil : driver.find_element(id: "ctl00_RadWindow1_C_btnOk").click
        sleep(5)
        area = driver.find_element(id: "lblarea").text
        zoning = driver.find_element(id: "lblzone").text
        print area
        print zoning
    end
end

Scrape.new.call
```

Please let me know if you can help me around to make it run.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question so much as an ask to troubleshoot your script for free.

Comment: I know this is not programming qns, and i did almost all troubleshoots from my end... Just looking solution if by bad luck someone faced it.